# Ошибка "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" при указании внешнего ключа для связи многие-ко-многим

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe (
    IDRecipe INT NOT NULL,
    IDIngredient INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Ingredients (IDIngredient), 
    IDDish INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Menu (IDDish));
```

Постоянно выводит ошибку:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Как ее исправить? Не могу понять, в чём дело.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Обратимся к [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE):

> When you specify a foreign key constraint **inline, you need only the references_clause**.
> When you specify a foreign key constraint **out of line, you must also specify the FOREIGN KEY** keywords and one or more columns.

Слепо верим тому, что там написано (выделено жирным, наш случай **inline**):

```
create table Ingredients (IDIngredient int primary key)
/
Table INGREDIENTS created.

create table Menu (IDDish int primary key)
/
Table MENU created.

create table Recipe (
    IDRecipe int not null, 
    IDIngredient int not null references Ingredients (IDIngredient), 
    IDDish       int not null references Menu (IDDish))
/
Table RECIPE created.
```